# Viewport-units vw/vh not working as expected when non-100% zoom in Safari on OS X

Tags: html, safari, viewport-units

I'm having trouble with `vw` and `vh` units on OSX Safari.

Take this code as an example:

```html
<body style="margin: 0;">
    <div style="background: red;
                height: 100vh;
                width: 100vw;"></div>
</body>
```

At 100% zoom, it works fine. However, if you zoom out, Chrome and Firefox (with this example) still render the red `div` across the whole page. Safari, on the other hand, seems to be rendering as if `vw` and `vh` are calculated against the viewport at zoom 100%.

Is this the expected behaviour or is this something Safari does differently to other browsers? Are there any other browsers that render `vw` and `vh` in the same way?

Answer (score 2):

As I know only Safari has Problems with recalculation. See this page for more known issues with this property: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Safari, which was reportedly closed in November 2017. It's unclear if it will land in Safari 12 or not.

Bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145614

Changeset: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/225277/webkit